# How to add a sequencial number to my insert query in mysql/php ps. not auto increment

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to insert a sequencial item number when everytime the user creates an exam. 
everytime he creates an exam it restarts to 1. I extremely need your help, people. More power. :)

here is my code:

```
$examid = $_SESSION['examid'];
$itemnum = 1;

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO exam_questions (question_description, question_type, question_exam_id) VALUES ('$question', '$type', '$examid')")or die(mysql_error());
$lastinsertid = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query("UPDATE exam_questions SET question_set_id='<??????????>' WHERE question_id='$lastinsertid' LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You can use an autoincrement column as part of a composite primary key with some database engines, which will restart its autoincrement from 1 for every change of the other composite key column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this with a join:

```
UPDATE exam_questions eq cross join
       (select max(question_set_id) as qsi
        from exam_questions
        where question_id='$lastinsertid'
       ) as const
    SET eq.question_set_id = const.qsi + 1
    WHERE question_id='$lastinsertid';
```

Comment: When updating a table, it is locked and you cannot select from it in the same query.

Comment: @Kolink . . . That restriction does not apply to tables used in `join`s.  You can see an example at SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c068/1).

Comment: Aah, fair enough. Clever.

Comment: Im a begginer at programming, should i copy paste that line and replace the "update" statement? or should I add some quotes?

Comment: Not Working :(  - @Gordon

Comment: It always store the value of 1, so it doesnt increment. -  @GordonLinoff

Comment: It worked. after i replaced the question_id with the question_exam_id. thanks @gordon.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(`id`) INTO @tmpvar FROM `exam_questions` WHERE `question_exam_id`='$examid';
INSERT INTO `exam_questions`
    (`question_description`,`question_type`,`question_exam_id`,`question_id`)
    VALUES ('$question','$type','$examid',@tmpvar+1);
```

Note that those will have to be sent as separate `mysql_query` calls, but it should work nicely. I'm also assuming that you've correctly escaped your parameters.